# How to store some fields in web Apache access logs as encrypted text

Tags: apache, logging

Apache web server has a very rich log format supported by mod_log_config. However, I want to encrypt some fields e.g client-ip while it is getting stored in apache logs. is there a way to achieve this...other than writing your own post processor for log files that scans log files and encrypts certain fields? Is there an apache built-in way to do it?

Comment: By encrypted I obviously mean base ASCII encoded e.g base64 encoded AES encrypted.

Comment: I am currently experimenting with using %{UNIQUE_ID}e via the mod_unique_id apache module..Will try to see if that can help track a specific request. But encrypting a specific field still is an open-ended question.